# Verify consecutive codes around a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have two tables:
Table 1 consists of `ID` and `INDX`. `INDX` is the date around the `CODE` from Table2 needs to be verified.
Table2 consists of `ID`, `CODE`, `DAT`, `QRTR`. `DAT` is the date on which the `CODE` is given with corresponding quarter of the year in `QRTR`.

Table1:

| ID | INDX |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014-06-07 |

Table2:

| ID | CODE | DAT | QRTR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2013-08-20 | 20133 |
| 1 | A | 2013-12-20 | 20134 |
| 1 | A | 2014-01-02 | 20141 |
| 1 | A | 2014-11-18 | 20144 |
| 1 | A | 2015-02-08 | 20151 |
| 1 | A | 2015-04-20 | 20152 |
| 1 | A | 2015-11-16 | 20154 |
| 1 | A | 2016-04-12 | 20162 |
| 1 | A | 2017-01-20 | 20171 |
| 1 | A | 2017-12-12 | 20174 |
| 1 | A | 2018-01-03 | 20181 |
| 1 | A | 2019-05-20 | 20193 |
| 1 | A | 2020-01-01 | 20201 |
| 1 | A | 2021-04-16 | 20212 |
| 1 | A | 2021-08-20 | 20213 |
| 1 | A | 2021-12-30 | 20214 |

Now I need to know if `CODE` 'A' was present within 300 days until `INDX` date.
If so, I need to verify if `CODE` 'A' is given at least one `QRTR` per year starting with the first data entry of `CODE` 'A' (within 300 days prior `INDX`) including the future `CODE`s.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    years.Year,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM table2 t2
            WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
                AND t2.CODE = 'A'
                AND years.Year = YEAR(DATEADD(QUARTER, t2.QRTR % 10 - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, t2.QRTR / 10 - 1900, '19000101')))
        ) THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS IsQuarterly
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID
        FROM table1
    ) AS t1
CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(DATEADD(QUARTER, (QRTR % 10) - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, (QRTR / 10) - 1900, '19000101'))) AS Year
        FROM table2
        WHERE CODE = 'A'
    ) AS years
ORDER BY
    t1.ID,
    years.Year;
```

Data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YY657Xa9).

For the sake of presentation clarity I just included `ID` 1 in the tables above.

With my query i just get if at least one `QRTR` a year `CODE` 'A' is present but i dont get information until which time `CODE` 'A' was present and whether there has been a new period of `CODE` 'A'.

I expect the following, because i think its better to derive a period on which the `CODE` 'A' was present at least one `QRTR` a year.

| ID | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-08-20 | 2021-12-30 |
| 2 | 2017-12-12 | 2019-05-20 |
| 2 | 2021-08-20 | 2021-12-30 |

I am not sure what will be the best solution to display the result.

Comment: Why doesn't row `1  A  2020-01-01  20201` count to join up the two parts for ID=1?

Comment: ID 1 has one period, because every year at least in one quarter A is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a classic Gaps-and-Islands problem.**

You first need to aggregate up the data per year, and check for the total count per year.

Then use gaps-and-islands techniques to split it into groups of rows which are consecutive years, finally taking the min and max dates for each of those groups.

> In older versions of SQL Server, use `YEAR(` instead of `DATETRUNC(year,`, the latter is more performant if available.

```sql
WITH Data AS (
    SELECT
      t2.ID,
      Year = DATETRUNC(year, t2.DAT),
      MinDate = MIN(t2.DAT),
      Maxdate = MAX(t2.DAT),
      PrevYear =   LAG(DATETRUNC(year, t2.DAT)) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ID ORDER BY DATETRUNC(year, t2.DAT)),
      NextYear =  LEAD(DATETRUNC(year, t2.DAT)) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ID ORDER BY DATETRUNC(year, t2.DAT))
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2
      ON t2.ID = t1.ID
     AND t2.DAT >= DATEADD(day, -300, t1.INDX)
    GROUP BY
      t2.ID,
      DATETRUNC(year, t2.DAT)
),
Islands AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      NextMaxDate = LEAD(d.MaxDate) OVER (PARTITION BY d.ID ORDER BY d.Year)
    FROM Data d
    WHERE d.PrevYear IS NULL
       OR d.PrevYear < DATEADD(year, -1, Year)
       OR d.NextYear IS NULL
       OR d.NextYear > DATEADD(year, 1, Year)
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Start = MinDate,
  [End] = ISNULL(NextMaxDate, MaxDate)
FROM Islands i
WHERE i.PrevYear IS NULL
   OR i.PrevYear < DATEADD(year, -1, Year);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/bMZF8x0Q)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got the proper filters you wanted around the dates so adjust as necessary. The main portion of the logic uses universally available date functions and there's no need to use the value in `qrtr` at all:

```
with data as (
    select t1.indx, t2.id, t2.dat,
        datediff(year, min(dat) over (partition by t2.id), t2.dat) -
        dense_rank() over (partition by t2.id order by year(t2.dat)) as grp
    from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
    where t2.code = 'A' and t2.dat >= dateadd(day, -300, t1.indx)
)
select id, min(dat) as min_dat, max(dat) as max_dat
from data
group by id, grp
order by id, min(dat);
```